# Process with finished thread never exits

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

**Why should a thread persist and prevent its process to exit, even after its target is done?**

> While this question uses an additional child-process, the underlaying issue is entirely rooted in multithreading. Therefore this basic issue can be reproduced with the `MainProcess` alone. 
>   (Edited by @Darkonaut)

I've made a class that inherits `multiprocessing.Process`:

```
class Task(Process):
    def run(self) :
        print("RUN")

        t = threading.Thread(target=do_some_work)
        t.start()
        # ...
        t.join()
        print("CLOSED")
```

And I start it in this way:

```
proc = Task()
proc.start()
proc.join()
print("JOINED")
```

But it won't join and the output will be like this:

```
>> RUN
>> CLOSED
```

I'm not using any kind of `Queues` and `Pipes`.

When I ran this on Ubuntu , I tracked the process with its pid. The Process still exists even after `print("CLOSED")` line is done without any exceptions. I also ran this on Windows and tracked the process in Task Manager. The process exits after `print("CLOSED")` and it's still not joining.

Another point is that on Ubuntu, when everything is stuck after `print("CLOSED")` and I press `Ctrl + C` , I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scheduler.py", line 164, in <module>
    scheduler.start()
  File "Scheduler.py", line 152, in start
    self.enqueueTask(plan)
  File "Scheduler.py", line 134, in enqueueTask
    proc.join()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 47, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
```

According to the last line, I guess the main process is waiting for something but what and why?

The problem seems to be with a non-daemon thread that I'm starting in the `run()` method of `Task`. **Making this thread a daemon thread solves the problem**, so I can surely say this thread is preventing my process to be closed even after its `MainThread` is done. I'm still confused because the target function of that non-daemon thread is done successfully.

Comment: The documentation says that after `close()` returns successfully most other methods won't work. Try checking `is_alive() ` before calling `join()`.

Comment: Basically the parent process is waiting for SIGCHLD signal. See :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exit-status-child-process-linux/

Comment: I can't replicate this on Ubuntu, Python 3.7.3. Does the issue persist when you only run the code you've shown us? Anyway, you're not supposed to call `Process.close()` a) while the child is still running, b) from the child itself.

Comment: @Darkonaut please read update 1 , I wanna know why a non-daemon  thread should exists and prevent process to be killed , even after its target is done after 30 seconds?

Comment: `self.close()` is removed now? We would need to see a minimal example with the thread, reproducing the problem.

Comment: @Darkonaut yes there was no need to self.close , by changing that thread's type to a daemon thread , problem is solved , but I still have question about it.

Comment: I will tell you about that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Why should a thread persist and prevent its process to exit, even after its target is done?**

While this question uses an additional child-process, the underlaying issue is entirely rooted in multithreading. Therefore this basic issue can be reproduced with the `MainProcess` alone. An answer involving an additional child-process can be found in [edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9005e781-62f3-40c5-a195-0bf9ca589411/view-source).

---

## Scenario

Without having seen what your new thread in your child process is really doing, a likely scenario for your observed behavior is that your `thread-1`
is starting ***yet another* `thread-2`**, you might be even unaware about. Possibly it's started from a third party library you are calling into, or to stay within the stdlib, `multiprocessing.Queue.put()` also starts a feeder-thread in the background.

This general scenario is not a `Process`-subclassing-issue nor related to calling `Process.close()` from within the child-process itself (incorrect usage, but without consequences).

The `MainThread` in a process is always the last thread in a process exiting and it is joining **non-daemonic** threads as part of its `_shutdown()`-routine. That's what keeps the `MainThread` in a limbo-state while its "surface"-work is already done.

> The problem is with a non-daemon thread that I'm starting in run() method of Task. so I can surely say that thread is preventing my process to be closed even after its `MainThread` is done. but I'm still confused because target function of that non-daemon thread is done successfully.

Now in this pictured scenario, your target function for `thread-1` *can* actually finish successfully. However this `thread-1` has started another `thread-2`, which then does something lasting very long, like blocking forever in worst case.

> Q: 
>   If `thread-1` itself is not the problem, why there is no hanging when you make `thread-1` a `daemon`?

It's because the daemon-flag's ["initial value is inherited from the creating thread"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects). So making `thread-1` a `daemon`, makes its descendant `thread-2` a `daemon` too, unless the `daemon`-flag for `thread-2` is set explicitly. Daemons are not joined on shutdown and the whole process "exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left".

Note that prior to [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#multiprocessing), non-daemonic threads created by `Process` have *not* been joined.
This divergent behaviour for threads outside the `MainProcess` has been fixed in [bpo-18966](https://bugs.python.org/issue18966).

---

## Code

To show this scenario is already reproducible with a simpler setup, the example below uses the `MainProcess` as process which won't exit.
`thread-2` here is a `Timer`-thread, which will start and call `threading.Barrier(parties=1).wait()` after 10 seconds. This `.wait()` call then will finish immediately with `parties=1`, or block forever with `parties=2` because no other party calling `.wait()` on this [`Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects) exists in our setup. This enables easy toggling of behavior we want to reproduce.

```
import threading

def blackbox(parties):
    """Dummy for starting thread we might not know about."""
    timer = threading.Timer(10, threading.Barrier(parties=parties).wait)  # Thread-2
    timer.name = "TimerThread"
    timer.start()


def t1_target(parties):  # Thread-1
    """Start another thread and exit without joining."""
    logger = get_mp_logger()
    logger.info(f"ALIVE: {[t.name for t in threading.enumerate()]}")
    blackbox(parties)
    logger.info(f"ALIVE: {[t.name for t in threading.enumerate()]}")
    logger.info("DONE")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import logging

    parties = 1
    daemon = False
    print(f"parties={parties}, daemon={daemon}")

    logger = get_mp_logger(logging.INFO)
    logger.info(f"ALIVE: {[t.name for t in threading.enumerate()]}")
    t = threading.Thread(target=t1_target, args=(parties,), daemon=daemon)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    logger.info(f"ALIVE: {[t.name for t in threading.enumerate()]}")    
    logger.info("DONE")
```

The log below is for `parties=1`, so there is no infinite blocking, but since `thread-2` is not a daemon-thread, `MainThread` will join it on shutdown. Note that `TimerThread` is still alive after `t1_target` is done. Of main interest here is how the `MainThread` needs ~10 seconds to go from `"DONE"` to `"process shutting down"`. These are the 10 seconds `TimerThread` is alive.

```
parties=1, daemon=False
[18:04:31,977 MainThread <module>] ALIVE: ['MainThread']
[18:04:31,977 Thread-1 t1_target] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'Thread-1']
[18:04:31,978 Thread-1 t1_target] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'Thread-1', 'TimerThread']
[18:04:31,978 Thread-1 t1_target] DONE
[18:04:31,978 MainThread <module>] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'TimerThread']
[18:04:31,978 MainThread <module>] DONE
[18:04:41,978 MainThread info] process shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
```

With `parties=2` it hangs forever at this stage,...

```
parties=2, daemon=False
[18:05:06,010 MainThread <module>] ALIVE: ['MainThread']
[18:05:06,010 Thread-1 t1_target] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'Thread-1']
[18:05:06,011 Thread-1 t1_target] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'Thread-1', 'TimerThread']
[18:05:06,011 Thread-1 t1_target] DONE
[18:05:06,011 MainThread <module>] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'TimerThread']
[18:05:06,011 MainThread <module>] DONE
```

...unless you also set `daemon=True`, either for `thread-1` (`thread-2` inheriting) or just for `thread-2` directly.

```
parties=2, daemon=True
[18:05:35,539 MainThread <module>] ALIVE: ['MainThread']
[18:05:35,539 Thread-1 t1_target] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'Thread-1']
[18:05:35,539 Thread-1 t1_target] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'Thread-1', 'TimerThread']
[18:05:35,539 Thread-1 t1_target] DONE
[18:05:35,539 MainThread <module>] ALIVE: ['MainThread', 'TimerThread']
[18:05:35,539 MainThread <module>] DONE
[18:05:35,539 MainThread info] process shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

**Helper**

```
DEFAULT_MP_FORMAT = \
    '[%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(threadName)s %(funcName)s]' \
    ' %(message)s'
DEFAULT_DATEFORMAT = "%H:%M:%S"  # "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"


def get_mp_logger(level=None, fmt=DEFAULT_MP_FORMAT, datefmt=DEFAULT_DATEFORMAT):
    """
    Initialize multiprocessing-logger if needed and return reference.
    """
    import multiprocessing.util as util
    import logging
    logger = util.get_logger()
    if not logger.handlers:
        logger = util.log_to_stderr(level)
    logger.handlers[0].setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt, datefmt))
    return logger
```

Comment: Such an amazing answer!

Comment: @AmirHmZ Did it hit your case, though? A mysterious second thread is the only scenario I can think of which reproduces your observed behaviour.

Comment: @Darkonuat Yes you hit the point up, how can I track running threads and understand which thread is blocking ?

Comment: @AmirHmZ From within Python you can track running threads in a process with [`threading.enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate) for example. I'm afraid there's not really a satisfying answer to this. I'm using logging or prints like in my example to find the point where it starts hanging. Also within stdlib-code if necessary and applicable. Then already knowing or reading up the docs about what could cause hanging in general gives you a hypothesis to investigate.

Comment: I tracked all threads using `threading.enumerate()` , I found my socket listener thread that was running nonstop :| so changed it to a daemon thread and problem is completely solved.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: your scenario was right from the first place , I'm just waiting 24 hours to give bounties to you cause **SO** doesn't let me. thanks again

Comment: @AmirHmZ You're welcome! :) I'm glad it was of help and thanks for the unexpected bounty of course! I will probably edit your question a bit later so more people who are likely to benefit from the answer have a chance of finding it.